# How do I download the content of a project in Visual Studio TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

How do I download the content of a project in Visual Studio TFS?  I clicked around and I did not find an easy or intuitive way to do it.  It is an old project that I thought had been lost until I reinstalled the latest version of Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to work on the project - check out files, make changes and check them back in?  Or do you just want a copy of the repository as a ZIP?

Comment: Can I have both?  I would love a copy of the code as a zip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the TFS project from Visual Studio. First, you have to connect the project via Team Explorer in Visual Studio then add a server and click 'select team project' and you're done. It is downloaded to your PC.

You can find a documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181387(v=vs.110).aspx).

**EDIT:**

Also, if you want to download your code as a zip:

You can click on any ellipsis to find the menu which contains `Download as Zip` option.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you merely want an archive of the contents of a folder, you can right-click on the folder in the tree view on the left hand side of the page (in this case, on `$/gelsana`) and select the option "Download as Zip".

This is suitable for archival purposes.  You cannot check-in changes made using this option.